# Cópia de projeto sem instalação do Framework Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

É possível copiar um projeto Laravel para um servidor sem que eu precise instalar o Laravel nesse servidor? É só copiar os arquivos ou tenho que fazer alguma configuração adicional, além de apontar o DNS para a pasta `public`?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com *Instalar o Laravel*? O que você tem que fazer é justamente copiar os arquivos e apontar o DNS, qual hospedagem tu usa?

Comment: Seria instalar o laravel no servidor. Achei que tivesse alguma limitação quanto a comandos internos do framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Se você estiver copiando manualmente o projeto

Você pode simplesmente copiar tudo e descompactar no servidor de destino, você precisa se atentar as permissões das pastas, a pasta 'storage' necessita chmod 777. E fazer a exportação do banco de dados obviamente.

## Se você estiver copiando um projeto de um repositório

Se você está pegando esse projeto de um repositório por exemplo é necessário que você tenha o git para clonar o projeto, e para baixar todas as dependências seria necessário o composer.

#### Instalação do Git

Se você quiser instalar o Git no Linux via um instalador binário, você pode fazê-lo com a ferramenta de gerenciamento de pacotes (packages) disponível na sua distribuição. Caso você esteja no Fedora, você pode usar o yum:

```
$ yum install git-core
```

Ou se você estiver em uma distribuição baseada no Debian, como o Ubuntu, use o apt-get:

```
$ apt-get install git
```

#### Instalação do composer

Para instalação do composer utilizando yum. Você vai até a pasta /tmp.

```
cd /tmp
```

Executa o seguinte código para realizar o download

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

En seguida você o move para o caminho /usr/local/bin/

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Pronto, você já pode usar o composer.

#### Instalando projeto

Depois de clonar o projeto utilizando o git, você realiza o download das dependências com o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
composer update
```

Ele ira baixar todas dependências existentes existentes. Nesses ca

Comment: Nossa, completíssimo rsrs. Obrigado, a cópia seria manual mesmo, eu tinha dúvidas se teria algum problema porque em outros projetos que trabalhei já tinha tudo instalado, eram só alterações, e agora como é um projeto novo me deparei com isso. De todo jeito, a minha ambição é futuramente sincronizar com o GIT mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: O processo é bem variável, não da pra te dar uma resposta definitiva que sirva para todos, mas qualquer dúvida comenta aqui que te auxilio.